# How to add marker after tap/click on map and Remove marker using google_maps in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

```dart
getMap() {
  //A unique id to name the div element
  String htmlId = "6";
  //creates a webview in dart
  //ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(htmlId, (int viewId) {
    final latLang = LatLng(18.508682857887514, 73.79985281545117);
    //class to create a div element

    final mapOptions = MapOptions()
      ..zoom = 11
      ..tilt = 90
      ..center = latLang;
    final elem = DivElement()
      ..id = htmlId
      ..style.width = "100%"
      ..style.height = "100%"
      ..style.border = "none";

    final map = GMap(elem, mapOptions);
    Marker(MarkerOptions()
      ..position = latLang
      ..map = map
      ..title = 'My position');
      Marker(MarkerOptions()
      ..position = LatLng(18.52362694783254, 73.87910089845153)
      ..map = map
      ..title = 'My position');
    Marker(MarkerOptions()
      ..position = LatLng(18.6206091576794, 73.91171656176442)
      ..map = map
      ..title = 'My position');

    return elem;
  });
  //creates a platform view for Flutter Web
  return HtmlElementView(
    viewType: htmlId,
  );
}
```

I've looked all around the internet, and I found many examples of adding markers, but not on map click. The google_maps_flutter_web and google_maps plugins don't mention anything about this yet. Is it possible to add the marker by tapping the map, or is this something that's still not available?

Answer (score 0):

```
late GMap _googleMap;

Map<String, Marker> _markers = {};


Widget getMap() {

    String htmlId = "7";

    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(htmlId, (int viewId) {
      final myLatlng = LatLng(1.3521, 103.8198);

      final mapOptions = MapOptions()
        ..zoom = 10
        ..center = LatLng(1.3521, 103.8198);

      final elem = DivElement()
        ..id = htmlId
        ..style.width = "100%"
        ..style.height = "100%"
        ..style.border = 'none';

      _googleMap = GMap(elem, mapOptions);
      _googleMap.onClick.listen((MapMouseEvent event) {
        addMarker(event.latLng!.toString(), event.latLng!);
      });

      return elem;
    });

    return HtmlElementView(viewType: htmlId);
  }
removeMarker(String markerId) {
    Marker? _marker = _markers[markerId];
    _marker?.set("map", null);
  }

  addMarker(String markerId, LatLng latLng) {
    _markers[markerId] = Marker(MarkerOptions()
      ..position = latLng
      ..map = _googleMap
      ..title = 'New marker ${markerId}');
    _markers[markerId]?.onClick.listen((MapMouseEvent event) {
      removeMarker(event.latLng!.toString());
    });
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).